# DXB Airport: Getting from Terminal 2, to Terminal 3 left luggage to gate in 3 hours

Tags: dubai, dxb

I'm heading into Africa and was hoping to leave a decent amount of my stuff in DXB so I can travel light while in Africa. I'm aware there is a [Left Luggage](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/baggage/baggage-services-dubai.aspx) option in Terminal 3 which is available to store my luggage for a few days (checked with Emirates).

My concern is if I were to do this, would I have enough time to retrieve my items.

- 04:45 - Fly into DXB terminal 2
- Pick up luggage from Left Luggage
- Go through security
- 08:00 - Fly out of DXB terminal 3

I'm also aware that it may [take up to 40 minutes](https://www.emirates.com/us/english/before-you-fly/dubai-international-airport/emirates-terminal-3/finding-your-way.aspx) to transfer between Terminal 2 and Terminal 3 and that the Left Luggage area is outside passport control meaning I would have to re-enter security after getting my luggage.

The question I have is if there is enough time to transit between Terminal 2, to the Left Luggage area and back through security to my gate in Terminal 3. Further, would it be faster if I left the secure area from Terminal 2 and grabbed a cab or use the dedicated bus service?

Comment: That sounds like it might be cutting it close. Those three hours are some of DXB's busiest. Can you ask the [Marhaba service](https://www.marhabaservices.com/) to take your bags to Left Luggage for you? I don't know if they will, and if they do they'll charge you a service fee, but it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: I think I'm going the other way... I would need to pick up my luggage from Left Luggage on my way to terminal 3. I'll update the timeline to emphasize this.

Comment: Either way, they ought to be able to help you in some way.